# What happens when you reach the edge of the world?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

In Minecraft, presumably the world is finite. What happens when you reach the edge of the world? Or will the world become too large to reasonably deal with before this happens?

Comment: See also: [The Far Lands](http://www.minecraftwiki.net/wiki/Far_Lands) at Minecraft Wiki.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

From [Notch's Tumblr](http://notch.tumblr.com/post/3746989361/terrain-generation-part-1):

> First of all, let me clarify some
> things about the “infinite” maps:
> They’re not infinite, but there’s no
> hard limit either. It’ll just get
> buggier and buggier the further out
> you are. Terrain is generated, saved
> and loaded, and (kind of) rendered in
> chunks of 16*16*128 blocks. These
> chunks have an offset value that is a
> 32 bit integer roughly in the range
> negative two billion to positive two
> billion. If you go outside that range
> (about 25% of the distance from where
> you are now to the sun), loading and
> saving chunks will start overwriting
> old chunks. At a 16/th of that
> distance, things that use integers for
> block positions, such as using items
> and pathfinding, will start
> overflowing and acting weird.
>
> Those are the two “hard” limits.
>
> Most other things, like the terrain
> generation seeds and entity locations
> use 64 bit doubles for locations, and
> they do much subtler things. For
> example, at extreme distances, the
> player may move slower than near the
> center of the world, due to rounding
> errors (the position has a huge
> mantissa, the movement delta has a
> tiny, so it gets cut off faster). The
> terrain generator can also start
> generating weird structures, such as
> huge blocks of solid material, but I
> haven’t seen this lately nor examined
> exactly what behavior causes it to
> happen. One major problem at long
> distances is that the physics starts
> bugging out, so the player can
> randomly fall into ground blocks or
> get stuck while walking along a wall.
>
> Many of these problems can be solved
> by changing the math into a local
> model centered around the player so
> the numbers all have vaguely the same
> magnitude. For rendering, Minecraft
> already uses local coordinates within
> the block and offset the block
> position relative to the player to
> give the impression of the player
> moving. This is mostly due to OpengGL
> using 32 bit floats for positions, but
> also because the rounding errors are
> extremely visible when displayed on a
> screen.
>
> We’re probably not going to fix these
> bugs until it becomes common for
> players to experience them while
> playing legitimately. My gut feeling
> is that nobody ever has so far, and
> nobody will. Walking that far will
> take a very long time. Besides, the
> bugs add mystery and charisma to the
> Far Lands.

As of Beta 1.8 [[source]](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Far_Lands):

> In beta 1.8 the strange terrain may be gone, but some of the effects
> aren't. After X/Z ±30,000,000 the world will start generating fake
> chunks. Going into the fake chunks will result in falling into the
> Void, and, subsequently, the player's death. If flying is used, going
> about 34 blocks out of the limit will cause you to be stuck, being
> able to use your inventory and look around, but not to move. Also, the
> clouds will act strangely, moving at abnormally high speeds. Reloading
> the save should fix the clouds, but the position glitch will still be
> present. Also, at excessive X/Z positions, particles (rain, water,
> snow, etc.) fail to appear staggered, instead forming rows of flat
> "panes". The Far Lands do not lag in 1.8. in 1.0.0 the fire of torches
> will be in/on a block next to it, instead of on the torch. In 1.0.0
> explosion clouds look abnormally big. Piston heads will disappears
> when the block is activated and will have the same effect as sand does
> when falling (then disappears). Paintings can be placed over paintings
> near the far lands. Also, the floating book in the enchantment table
> seems to behave abnormally when a player is moving near it. Redstone
> appears either extremely distorted, with stretched graphics, it can
> appear misplaced, or it can appear completely invisible, but the
> highlight box still appears indicating where redstone is placed.
> Cauldrons, when looked from the inside, one of the sides is
> translucent, and the graphics for that side appear one block away from
> the cauldron on the opposite side of where the texture is missing
> from. Highlight box for cake fails to appear correctly. Flames from a
> monster spawner only appear on one side of the block. The graphic for
> end portal block fail to appear correctly.

Comment: That doesn't really help much.  How far exactly is `25% between you an the sun?`

Comment: 23238971.9 miles via a quick Google. Not sure if Notch was being literal as you are though.

Comment: Miles?  I thought he was referring to the position of the Sun in Minecraft, which I don't know anything about.  As I re-read, I realize that I may have missed an attempt to relate the size of the Minecraft world to RL.

Comment: Yea, I sort of read it as really farking large

Comment: The sun in minecraft is on the sky, it's not a physical object you can go to.

Comment: @Phoshi maybe it is

Comment: @Jader Dias; it isn't :P

Comment: Notch means the real Sun. 32-bit integers means 2^31 chunks in any direction from spawn, which is (2^31)*16 blocks, each a meter cubed giving (2^31)*(16/1000) km (Minecraft uses metric). [The Earth's distance to the Sun](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Astronomical_unit) is roughly 149,597,870.7 km, giving a ratio of (2^31)*(16/1000)/1 au = 23%, [which is the number that Notch has given](http://notch.tumblr.com/post/3746989361/terrain-generation-part-1). So it's incredibly huge and impossible to hit this limit in a lifetime on foot. Even the 1/16th limit is difficult to hit.

Comment: So we can't build the Ringworld?!  ARGH!!!!

Comment: @Loren: How many Earths fit in its width alone? Like 100+? I think we can't even build a cross-section of Ringworld :P

Comment: We could build a cross-section but I think that would get into some of the far lands dangers.

Comment: Updated the answer since this still gets upvotes occasionally. I'd hate to lead people hunting for strange terrain that no longer exists.

Comment: I kinda would have liked to be able to reach the minecraft sun...

Answer (score 25):

A few patches ago the world was practically infinite (couple of million kilometers) but with the later updates problems occur closer to the 0 point (around 8000 kilometers)

As seen in the video (not mine) bounding boxes will be located differently from the cubes themselves, movement stutters and various other problems come up (going even further renders the game completely unplayable).

This still leaves you with around (2*8000)*(2*8000) = 256000000 square kilometers of playable surfaces area (the distances only matter on 1 axes for the most part so its a roughly square surface, its also times two cause you can go 8000 kilometers both north and south)

Answer (score 15):

Notch himself wrote [a blog post](http://notch.tumblr.com/post/3746989361/terrain-generation-part-1) about Minecraft's world generation.

Short answer: The maps are infinite (until your hard drive fills up), but will become buggier the bigger they are.

Long answer:

> **How infinite is it?**
>
> First of all, let me clarify some things about the “infinite” maps: They’re not infinite, but there’s no hard limit either. It’ll just get buggier and buggier the further out you are. Terrain is generated, saved and loaded, and (kind of) rendered in chunks of 16*16*128 blocks. These chunks have an offset value that is a 32 bit integer roughly in the range negative two billion to positive two billion. If you go outside that range (about 25% of the distance from where you are now to the sun), loading and saving chunks will start overwriting old chunks. At a 16/th of that distance, things that use integers for block positions, such as using items and pathfinding, will start overflowing and acting weird.
>
> Those are the two “hard” limits.
>
> Most other things, like the terrain generation seeds and entity locations use 64 bit doubles for locations, and they do much subtler things. For example, at extreme distances, the player may move slower than near the center of the world, due to rounding errors (the position has a huge mantissa, the movement delta has a tiny, so it gets cut off faster). The terrain generator can also start generating weird structures, such as huge blocks of solid material, but I haven’t seen this lately nor examined exactly what behavior causes it to happen. One major problem at long distances is that the physics starts bugging out, so the player can randomly fall into ground blocks or get stuck while walking along a wall. - Notch

Answer (score 10):

The map is pretty much infinite. The Far Lands do get quite weird over time, because, as Notch stated, problems in the map generator produce some weird effects.

As close as 500,000 blocks away from your spawn point, the frame rate starts to slow down. As you get further and further away, the framerate keeps on slowing down to the point where you cannot move at all. Then Minecraft crashes.

The point in which the Far Lands really begin, however, is at X/Z 12,550,821. The terrain generator starts going crazy, producing amazingly tall and smooth floating structures that keep on going to infinity. The Far Lands are monster magnets, because the spaces between one structure and another are pitch black, so they are able to spawn.

At X/Z 32,000,000, the terrain generator goes out of control. The structures don't change, however now there is no lighting, trees, monsters or animals. You will have to use a mod to fly now, because now the block positioning system is out of control too. If you are not flying, you will fall through the blocks into the Void (yes, even the Bedrock goes crazy). While you are flying, try to  break a block at the top of the Far Lands. First you will find out that it is very hard to do so. Second, when you have done it, the hole in the block shakes from side to side.

At X/Z of ±2,147,483,648, positions of items, mob pathfinding and other things using 32-bit integers will overflow and act weird, usually resulting in Minecraft crashing.

Finally,  at the hard limit which is at about X/Z ±34,359,738,368 (if you convert that to meters, is is one-quarter of the way from the Earth to the Sun), blocks and chunks will simply stop generating.

Sources:

https://minecraft.wiki/w/Far_Lands

Comment: The game doesn't neccesarily slow down when you get 500,000 blocks away from spawn, player movement just gets buggier and buggier.