# Is the Nether infinite?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

If I were to mine netherrack upwards or downwards, left or right in one direction, would I hit bedrock, or would I keep on going? What would happen?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

From Minecraft Wiki's page on [The Nether](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Nether#Terrain_and_Characteristics):

> ... Under the Lava ocean, there is a layer of Nettherack<sup>1</sup> and Bedrock on the very bottom. Similarly, the very top of the Nether is Bedrock.

<sup>1</sup> Or Bloodstone

Basically, going up or down either way leads to Bedrock.

[image]

Comment: Out of curiosity, is the bedrock on the top smooth or rough like the bottom in the Overworld?

Comment: @Ullallulloo Rough

Comment: What about left and right?

Comment: @Alexy13 Provided you actually go **really** far, you will reach the Far Lands.

Comment: Really far, as in 32,000,000 (or more) blocks.

Comment: This doesn't actually answer the question?

Answer (score 14):

The Nether is as infinite as the surface horizontally, however, like the surface it is limited to 128 blocks in height. The only difference is that in the Nether there is bedrock above *and* below, whereas the surface only has it below.

Answer (score 3):

To be technical, neither the Nether nor the surface are infinite (both however are VERY VERY VERY LARGE).  Regardless of horizontal limits however, ther vertical limit is 128 blocks, just as the surface is.

Comment: That's not really true.  See http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/19179/what-happens-when-you-reach-the-edge-of-the-world

Comment: @bwarner And to that I give you http://notch.tumblr.com/post/422515389/clearing-up-the-world-size-math

Comment: That post is from 2010 and appears to be out of date.  The one linked in the questions is from 2011 and references "When I changed the game over from being just single zones of a map to an infinite map"

Comment: @bwarner Ahh, I haven't keeping up with the updates as of late.  I have some catching up to do! :)

Comment: @bwarner The map is broken at around 12 million blocks from the centre. For all intents and purposes, that may as well be the end of the map. http://www.minecraftwiki.net/wiki/Far_Lands

Answer (score 0):

[image]

So while I was flying in the nether I hit a big wall of bedrock, so technically the nether isn't infinite in either sides

Comment: Unless the bedrock continues on eternally. Also, did you come across it in all directions? Does it depend on the map?