# How long would it take to circumnavigate the minecraft "planet"?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

If I had a ***very*** long stretch of powered rail going in one direction, would I be able to eventually circumnavigate the planet? and if so, how long would it take?

(Assume the track is entirely flat and I burrow through all mountains I hit)

Comment: I think you may want to add a few more very's.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Minecraft subscribes to the "Flat Earth" theory. Discounting mods, you can never circumnavigate the planet, as the "planet" will simply expand longer and longer in whichever direction you travel.

Comment: Well, there must be a edge, I mean I am pretty sure Notch is not using arbitrary precision numbers, eventually it must overflow.

Comment: @Scott, I suggest you check out the answer to [this question!](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/19179/what-happens-when-you-reach-the-edge-of-the-world)

Comment: Are there actually any 'round earth' mods?

Comment: It doesn't overflow in a simple way such that you'll suddenly find yourself at the "other side" of the flat map. Various Minecraft internals using different precisions start behaving badly and make the game unplayably slow long before any of them overflow.

Comment: There is an End of the Flat world. I never went there myself but according to the Minecraft Wiki it does exist. It is called the "Far Lands" http://www.minecraftwiki.net/wiki/Far_Lands

Comment: @Diskilla - There *used* to be. They've since been removed.

Comment: @Raven Dreamer Thanks. Didn´t know that. Enabling Javascript on the minecraftwiki page is helpfull ^^ It is written on top of the article I postet earlier... -.-