# How do I get the end of the world?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I sometimes like to make a game in which I create a new non-superflat world, I play in it in creative, and explore.

But, I have never gotten to the end of the world. How can you get there?

And is it easy?

Comment: In theory there's no end, but in practice weird crap starts happening at certain boundaries: http://www.minecraftwiki.net/wiki/Far_Lands#In_Beta_1.8_and_above

Comment: @fredley Well, Minecraft worlds do have ends, they just aren't easily accessible.

Comment: Pretty sure the Pocket Edition has an end. I came across a spot where the land/sea just...ended. No more chunks. Just nothingness. It was...strangely beautiful. They should have sent a poet. Or it could have just been a bug.

Comment: @Alex PE worlds are limited, yes. Same as Xbox worlds (for now). Minecraft, Minecraft Xbox, and Minecraft PE are different games though, with different tags here.

Comment: Hey, why did you close this?

Comment: This was closed for the wrong reason, it is a duplicate not "not a real question".

Comment: @Resorath Duplicate of? Please do link, since that's my feeling too but I haven't found the question I'm thinking this might be a duplicate of.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie The duplicate is listed under "linked" already, but here it is again: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/19179/what-happens-when-you-reach-the-edge-of-the-world?lq=1

Comment: Oh, I already looked at that one. That's what I'd call a related question, not a duplicate. That is asking what's at the edge of the world, and this is asking how to get there. The answers there don't even mention how to get there. It's as different as "What happens to my stuff when I die?" is from "How do I prevent losing stuff when I die?"

Comment: [Relevant.](http://towardsdawns.blogspot.com/)

Comment: @Beska Why do you feel so strongly that the title needed "Minecraft" in it? (Judging by your edit comment, you feel *very* strongly about it.) It's not strictly wrong, but why? We have soft a policy against editing just to put the game name into the title (see [here](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/821/question-with-vague-title) and [here](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/6950/when-should-we-edit-game-names-out-of-question-titles-and-why?rq=1)), so what makes this question an exception?

Comment: @SevenSidedDie  Hmm...I probably worded the comment too strongly. It's something I have an opinion about, but definitely didn't intend to offend. It's an issue that has also been discussed on other sites...the general consensus I've seen is that while the the game name should definitely be a tag, it should also be in the question title if the question doesn't make sense without it. This question, for example, is showing up in the "hot questions" dropdown area for StackExchange sites...but from the question title without the game name, it's not clear what the question is about.

Comment: @Beska Ah. Please do read those two meta posts then, since [ambiguous titles showing up in places like that has been explicitly addressed](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/821/question-with-vague-title/822#822) and deemed a feature, not a problem.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Actually, in the second link you mention, the top answer specifically agrees with me: "In cases like this, where the question itself is completely generic and applies to many games, adding the title perfectly acceptable, it might be even necessary to circumvent the duplicate title check (you can't have two questions with exactly the same title on the site)."  The top answer for the other question seems to indicate the opposite point...that ambiguity is somehow a "feature" because it encourages curiosity.  Bleh.  I can be curious without people hiding information from me.

Comment: @Beska "Completely generic and applies to many games" is to avoid *exact* title matches (which the software doesn't allow), like in the question's example. When that's not a problem like here, we avoid changing the title. Changing it *just* so that the game is in the title does not have community support, due to the immense mess it would make of the question list.

Comment: I can't believe it. I thought you would close my question. But it made my win a lot of Rep!!!! Tnaks to all you guys!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What happens when you reach the edge of the world?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/19179/what-happens-when-you-reach-the-edge-of-the-world)

Comment: @pppery  "How do I get to" is a different question to "What happens when you reach the". Different questions, different answers. Voting to leave open. They're related, but not a dupe.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

In older versions of Minecraft there was an edge of the map called the [Far Lands](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Far_Lands#Getting_to_the_Far_Lands). However, since Beta 1.8, the Far Lands act a bit differently:

> In [Beta] 1.8, instead of the Far Lands starting to generate at 12,550,820
> meters from the center of the map, the playable area abruptly ends at
> 30,000,000 meters, and fake chunks (they are not solid, they can be
> fallen through) start generating. A sure sign that one has reached the
> edge of the map is that lighting no longer works past the 30,000,000th
> mark. Versions between Alpha 1.2.0 (Halloween Update) and Beta 1.7.3
> rendered fake chunks outside of a limit of 32,000,000 meters;
> attempting to walk onto them would cause the player to die in the
> Void. From the beginning of Infdev all the way to the Halloween
> Update, the world abruptly ended at 32,000,000 meters, and leaving the
> boundary caused you to be trapped rather than die.

To get to the 'Far Lands' you can follow the instructions in the Minecraft Wikia. However, as it says in the first sentence there is no easy way to get to the edge without using commands or external programs (Though there is a [long running series](http://farlandsorbust.com/) that attempts to walk to the Far Lands, he is currently on episode 255). It is also prone to make your Minecraft crash so try it at your own risk.

> Getting to the Far Lands without the use of an external program was a
> very difficult (or at least time consuming) task, as walking to there
> from the center of the map would have taken approximately 820 hours
> (or 34 days). Instead, a level.dat editor could be used to teleport
> the player there.
>
> The boundary between the normal map and the Far Lands (defined by when
> the map started generating the distorted terrain) occurred at X/Z of
> ±12,550,821.
>
> The hard limit where chunks are overwritten is at X/Z of
> ±34,359,738,368, which is about 23% of the distance from the Earth to
> the Sun. At X/Z of ±2,147,483,648 (crashes at 2,147,483,439), item
> positions, mob pathfinding and other things using 32-bit integers will
> overflow and act strangely, usually resulting in Minecraft crashing.
>
> At X/Z of ±1.798*10<sup>308</sup>, the position of the player, represented by a
> double-precision floating point number, would overflow to 'infinity',
> causing a complete breakdown of arithmetic. Even at far smaller
> coordinates, the limited precision would cause errors in calculations.
> For example, at 10<sup>16</sup>, xPosition + 1 is equal to xPosition.
>
> Using Single Player Commands, it is very easy to get to the Far Lands
> using teleportation. After pressing the chat key (default "T") to open
> up the console-like input window, using the "teleport" command (or its
> abbreviation, "tp") followed by X, Y, and Z coordinates will allow the
> player to go wherever they want. In Release 1.3, you can turn on
> cheats to teleport. For example:
>
> To get to where the Edge Far Lands' wall was, try "/tp 12550820 129 0". Make sure either flying is turned on or damage is turned off,
> as otherwise you'll fall to your death.
> To get to where the Corner Far Lands were (the walls' intersection), try "/tp 12550820 129 12550820". Again, make sure
> you're protected from fall damage.
>
> Unfortunately, there was severe lag, and slower computers used to
> crash upon this teleportation. Opening a GUI helped the Far Lands
> render much, much faster. You can do this by pausing (pressing Escape)
> or opening the Single Player Commands prompt again. When you venture
> out farther above and into the far lands, the probability increases
> that a "bad chunk" will appear. A bad chunk is a chunk filled with
> terribly corrupt data, and is the cause of sudden lag spikes that can
> easily make Minecraft crash.

Here is a question related to the [Far Lands](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/19179/what-happens-when-you-reach-the-edge-of-the-world)

Comment: Makes me want to get to our own universe's "Far Lands", where the programming of our reality begins to overflow and break.

Comment: @Jeff that's called Australia.

Comment: @Alex - Oi! Don't make me get outta my kangaroo... :P

Comment: Don't worry, just learned about /tp x y z!

Comment: @AnonymousPi If you feel like this answer covered everything you wanted then click the check mark next to it for answer accepted. Not required or anything, just a best practice.

Answer (score 7):

Unfortunately, most of these answers are outdated, so here's one from 1.8.

You *can* reach the end of the world, but it requires teleporting. At the end of the world, you are met with the World Border.

[image]

This can only be crossed on one side, and that is to get *in*, not *out*. The only way to get past the WorldBorder is to use the  `/tp (playername) 29999999 100 29999999` command. (Note, do NOT try to walk. If you need to prove this yourself, teleport. Here's why:)

[image]

If you end up teleporting outside, you can fly back. There isn't much to do here. If you want to fall out of the world, **You can't.** Sorry, but another, invisible, world border greets you. Unfortunately, if you were to teleport outside, that would be the limit to how far you can teleport. You would just get an error message and a dilemma.

[image]

Other than curiosity, there is no real reason to be here. Because of the dangers of players breaking the world border, you can place blocks, but not break them.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I've called it the Unknown since it is very creepy. In PE you want Pocketinveditor and Select a world, tap Edit World Terrain, and Tap Move Player. Now Type for X and Y: 12550745 and Z: 90.

Tap OK, tap the back button on your Tablet or Phone, Exit, Get on Minecraft, Select the world you edited, and you should be flying since if you fall, you die. That Far land, WHOA! Even creepier than PC!

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
/tp 29999999 128 29999999
```

me teloported out of worldborder.
you cant go 100 blocks out of worldborder :D

Answer (score 0):

In version 1.5.2, `/tp 29999999 100 15000000` got me to the far lands. Go in creative because you might fall down the fake chunks. All the redstone and fire and cauldron and piston glitches happen.

Answer (score 0):

It is in fact possible to teleport past the second, invisible border. Just put this in once you're at it:

```
/tp @p ~+100 100 ~+100
```

The problem is, you can't move, you can't hold blocks right, and your character is invisible. You'll still die in survival but if you switch to creative before you die, you get a cool little shaky camera. It's pretty fun.

Answer (score -3):

Try:

```
/tp <selector> 29999999 106 29999999
```

Then you're on fake chunks and water everywhere is dirt

If you're playing as a guest offline try

```
/tp <selector> 29999999 106 299999999
```

This only works in a default world in 1.5.2.

Comment: Someone really should comment on why this is getting downvoted. The OP never said he didn't wish to use commands, I don't own minecraft so I don't know if this works or not.

Comment: @Cole It's getting downvoted because this is already said in the accepted answer, and doesn't add anything substantial, as new answers on solved questions are expected to do. So, it is "not useful", as the downvote tooltip says.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie I meant for River... but thanks for letting me know as well.

Comment: @ColeBusby Votes are anonymous for good reasons, so there is no "really should" about explaining them. If they think it will help, people will. Drive-by users who don't bother to read other answers to see that the problem has been solved are a dime a dozen are almost never stay though, so I am not surprised nobody bothered. Users who seem to be sticking around and who get the idea that downvotes must always be explained, though: they are worth correcting. :)

Comment: I don't care using commands. I actually use Creative much more than  Survival, and I always enable commands.