# How to find a nether fortress in Minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I need help finding a nether fortress. I'm new to Minecraft and I've searched many times and I always die trying to find one. Any tips?

The seed is 2667099037291472039 if anyone is willing to try find one.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Any useful strategies for finding a Nether Fortress?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/75073/any-useful-strategies-for-finding-a-nether-fortress) and/or [What are nether fortesses and how can I find them?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/147543/4797)

Answer (score 1):

Since you know your seed, this is easy to do:

Just place your seed into the tool on [chuckbase](https://chunkbase.com/apps/nether-fortress-finder)
(There are other tools online in case this link is dead in the far future)

Then you can check your coordinates on your F3 screen and just go there.

Answer (score 0):

Nether Fortresses aren't usually that hard to find, but according to the Minecraft Wiki it can take a long while to find one if you travel along the Z-Axis (north and south). Therefore it's much easier to come across one if you travel along the X-Axis (east or west).

I can't guarantee that you won't die on the way there though so all I can do is wish you luck for trying to get to one.

Minecraft Wiki Page about Nether Fortresses:
https://minecraft.wiki/w/Fortress